# Post class does not have objects variable in Django for Beginners

Tags: django, testing

In W S Vincent's "Django for Beginners," on page 71 he creates a simple message board Django project and then creates some testing code. His simple Post class is

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text[:50]
```

and then he creates a tests.py class with the following code:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import reverse #new
from .models import Post

class PostModelTest(TestCase):

    def setup(self):
        Post.objects.create(text='just a test')

    def test_text_content(self):
        post = Post.objects.get(id=1)
        expected_object_name = f'{post.text}'
        self.assertEqual(expected_object_name, 'just a test')
```

However, as you can see, there is no Posts.objects variable or method, and the test fails.  I don't see what he intended to do here, but those with more Django experience may be able to point out what is wrong.

Here is the trail of errors:

```
PS C:\Users\James\djangoproj\mb> python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
..E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_text_content (posts.tests.PostModelTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\James\djangoproj\mb\posts\tests.py", line 15, in test_text_content
    post = Post.objects.get(id=1)
  File "C:\Users\James\.virtualenvs\mb-e_xySg6P\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\James\.virtualenvs\mb-e_xySg6P\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 429, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
posts.models.Post.DoesNotExist: Post matching query does not exist.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.018s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Comment: The `.objects` is not something you define, this is something a Django model will define, given you do not add a model manager yourself.

Comment: If this is correctly copied from the book, then move to a different book. This introduces bad practices and what he calls "expected" is what we normally call "actual". Surrouding post.text with an f string also makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

A `Model` will have an `objects` manager, given you do not provide another manager. The Django meta-class logic will add the `.objects` manager.

The reason that the test fails is not because of a missing `.objects` attribute, it is because the `setUp(…)` method is with an uppercase `U`:

```
class PostModelTest(TestCase):

    # setUp instead of setup
    def setUp(self):
        Post.objects.create(text='just a test')

    def test_text_content(self):
        post = Post.objects.get(id=1)
        expected_object_name = f'{post.text}'
        self.assertEqual(expected_object_name, 'just a test')
```

It is furthermore *risky* to write the test like this, since the database is responsible to dispatch values for the `id` column (also something the Django meta-class logic defines here), You probably should rewrite this to:

```
class PostModelTest(TestCase):
    
    def setUp(self):
        self.post_id = Post.objects.create(text='just a test').pk

    def test_text_content(self):
        post = Post.objects.get(id=self.post_id)
        expected_object_name = f'{post.text}'
        self.assertEqual(expected_object_name, 'just a test')
```

Comment: Please change expected to actual. I got so confused just now :D.

Comment: Here are the reported errors. Spelling of setUp change made no deifference

Comment: @James: the error says simply it can not find an object with `id=1`, but this is exactly the point of the second code block. It *creates* an object, but likely the database gives it another primary key than `1`. What is `self.post_id`?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if its an issue with your models file. Is your version identical to the below?

from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
text = models.TextField()

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.text[:50]
```